# How do I remove Inbox as my search engine?

Tags: firefox, uninstall

Can anyone tell me how to remove inbox as my spammed search engine.  I went to tools and removed everything and it will not remove... It will not allow me to use Google or yahoo.  thanks
bill

Comment: Could you try to reword your question? Its not very clear.

Comment: It sounds like there's some kind of Inbox.com search plugin for Firefox that is really hard to remove.  I would imagine this is what bill is talking about: http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/698166

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like your default search engine got changed to the Inbox.com search engine, which is known for being [really hard to remove](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/698166).  It's possible that you've already uninstalled the actual extension, but some of the preferences that it changed are still set.

To fix things:

1. Type `about:config` into the Location Bar, and press Enter.
2. If you haven't done this before, Firefox will warn you about voiding your warranty.  Click "I'll be careful, I promise!"
3. In the box labeled "Filter" do a search for "browser.search".
4. Anything that was changed by the Inbox.com extension should be in bold.  Right click on anything that looks related to Inbox.com and choose "Reset".  You'll probably want to make sure that `browser.search.defaultenginename` and `browser.search.order.1` are both set to Google or Yahoo.

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 1):

I had downloaded "inbox.com" just to evaluate. To remove it I went to tools in the firefox menu at the top. Then went to addons. From there I was able to remove inbox.com